# How can I view a web application with insecure and secure requests in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, https, xmlhttprequest

When testing an application locally I am building, it is convenient for me to allow the application to make requests over http and https. But, Chrome is not happy with this and will not allow the insecure requests to complete. How do I convince Chrome to allow this mix of insecure and secure XHR requests in the application I am testing?

Answer (score 3):

**Problem:** Google, by default, will complain if you try to run a web application with both secure and insecure requests.

**Solution:** Start an instance of Chrome or Chromium with an option to allow the mix of secure and insecure requests.

1. Open Terminal (OS X) or the Command Prompt (MS)
2. Fire off the following command to open an "indifferent" instance of Chrome:

OS X: `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --allow-running-insecure-content`

MS: `start Chrome --allow-running-insecure-content`

Now, if you already have Chrome open, then this will open a tab in the existing instance of the Chrome app. You will then have an insecure tab floating around with your other tabs. You might forget that tab is insecure or this may at some point lead to a security breach. So, you could open a new instance of chrome by adding an option to the command to use a new temporary directory for your user information like so:

OS X: `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/tempchrome --allow-running-insecure-content`

MS: `start Chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/tempchrome --allow-running-insecure-content`

**Some Convenience Additions:**
Issuing this whole command every time you want to run something with a mix of secure and insecure content can get pretty tedious. I added this alias to my ~/.bash_profile to make opening Chrome in this mixed mode more convenient:

OS X: `alias chrome-insecure="/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/tempchrome --allow-running-insecure-content"`

MS: `a little help here?`

I also have an app I repeatedly test locally so I added the domain to open by default when my indifferent Chrome instance opened up like so:

OS X: `alias chrome-insecure="/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome localhost --user-data-dir=/tmp/tempchrome --allow-running-insecure-content"`

MS: `a little help here?`